# Automatically fill formula adjacent to pivottable on update

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

1. Create a column adjacent to a pivottable whose rows contain a formula.
2. Fill the formula down to the bottom of the pivottable.
3. Modify the pivottable source so that refreshing it changes the number of rows it contains.

**Desired behavior:** Adjacent column resizes to match the new number of rows in the pivottable.

I feel like I have seen this behavior before, but I can't reproduce it....

Comment: Yes,, if source value changes the formula also get new values,,, an adjacent column to TABLE / PT behaves like normal columns. Since U have not provided any data or shared the file on cloud/Drop Box,, then difficult to examine the real data. Better you create CALCULATED Field to get regular updates.

Comment: **Cont,,,**  sometimes you need to use Refresh All for the Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

I always wondered about this myself and I came up with a partial solution using formulas. It only works for one category. I believe it is possible to do a multi-category solution with the addition of `INDEX`, but the formula would become complicated (but more so, I am not up to the challenge today).

Anyway here is the one category solution:

(1) create your data and pivot table like normal and add a formula; it should look like this:
[image]

(2) change the highlighted item to a formula grabbing unique items (the `UNIQUE` function is only available in newer versions of Excel) from the original data table and sorting it:

[image]

Looking at it without formula preview it should look like this:

[image]

Anyway, when you add a new row in your data you should get this:
[image]

And a refresh of the pivot:

[image]

Comment: Clever use of one of the few [dynamic array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) we have!